# TouchPoint in JavaFX on Raspberry Pi sometimes defaults coordinates to zero

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

I'm building a JavaFX app for Raspberry Pi 3B+ with official 7" touchscreen (800x480). I'm using latest headless Raspbian Jessie. The screen is powered through the Raspberry Pi via jumper wires, and connected with the DSI ribbon cable. The app has a vertical layout, so I rotate the image using `display_rotate=3` in config.txt and I rotate the touch inputs in JavaFX itself, using the following JVM parameters (`dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406,touchscreen-swapped-x-y=1,touchscreen-inverted-y=1,touchscreen-size-x=480` in config.txt gives the same result):

```
-Dmonocle.input.0/0/0/0.minX=0
-Dmonocle.input.0/0/0/0.maxX=480
-Dmonocle.input.0/0/0/0.minY=480
-Dmonocle.input.0/0/0/0.maxY=-320
-Dmonocle.input.0/0/0/0.flipXY=true
```

Now, this works most of the time. However, in some cases (it's easy to reproduce by tapping fast at the same point), the touchpoint doesn't register properly, and one of the coordinates comes back as 0, like `0.0, 765.0` or `442.0, 0.0` (so if the user tries to press the button, nothing happens, since the touch gets thrown to the left/top side). This can happen at any point on the screen and it doesn't seem to be tied to CPU load. Right now I'm using Liberica JDK 10, before I used OpenJDK8, the bug was present in both cases. What can I do about it, is there a way to re-poll the screen manually?
I use the following code to register touchpoint coordinates(root is the main Node of the application)

```
root.setOnTouchPressed(event -> {
            TouchPoint point = event.getTouchPoint();
            System.out.println(point.getSceneX() + "," + point.getSceneY());
        });
```

Comment: How are you recording touch points? Can you add your code?

Comment: @Vulcan I took the root node of the app and used the `root.setOnTouchPressed(event -> {
            TouchPoint point = event.getTouchPoint();
            System.out.println(point.getSceneX() + "," + point.getSceneY());
        });`
However, even without that, I had the buttons at the top of the app that would get triggered sometimes, this was what warranted the investigation

Comment: I haven't used Java for a Pi touchscreen but when I created a similarly rotated touchscreen project with Python and pygame, I noticed that one or both of the coordinates (I can't recall) became 0 upon mouse release. I suspect that the touchscreen, on mouse release, is recording coordinates as 0 and JavaFX is failing to properly distinguish between multiple presses and releases in quick succession, leading to the released 0 coordinate leaking into the touch press event. If you add a similar event handler to the touch released handler, do you notice anything that could confirm this?

Comment: Maybe [this known unresolved JDK bug is related](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193038).

Comment: @Vulcan I've tried adding the same handler to the released event, the coordinates are identical (I don't know if this is relevant, but Oracle [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/touch_events.htm) (in "Additional Events Generated from Touches" paragraph) that touch events _generate_ mouse events in this case, not the other way around)

Comment: Whoops I meant touch press/release everywhere I said mouse in my last comment, I'm used to working with mouse rather than touch. Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: Does the event set ID reveal any patterns between the working and non working touch presses? I wonder if the quick-succession presses are being registered as the same event set.

Comment: Linked bug is likely unrelated, it says "Note that on the console output a "touch pressed" event does occur when you touch the buttton with your finger, but this does not cause the button's pressed property to become true", while in my case touch press does not occur on the button, the EventTarget becomes my root GridPane

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of eventsetid, it's "1" every time

Comment: I learned of event set ID just now [from this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/touch_events.htm) and it's used for determining sequences of events (i.e. a press followed by a move while pressed followed by a release). I'm grasping at straws for anything you may be able to use to distinguish the bugged events from normal ones so you can filter them out from your normal touch handling.

Comment: @Vulcan I added setOnMouseClicked handler and you're right, it is _somehow_ related, since turns out it registers _only_ bugged out events. Now the question is, how do I get non-bugged out events though. I'll try to disable mouse support

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to do anything, since as stated before, it's the touchevents that generate mouseevents, not the other way around. And I was seeing mouseclicked events because of mousemoved events (interestingly enough, the touchmoved were not generated). So, the question stands, for now I am unable to get proper touchpoints consistently (and there's no point in repeating the last known touch events, since these happen randomly, not just when tapping in the same spot)

Comment: Bummer. I wish I had a touchscreen to explore this issue on my Pi, it's an interesting bug. Are you able to test any other programs to discern whether its an issue with JavaFX specifically or maybe if it could be a hardware or other configuration issue?

Comment: I want to experiment with Qt on the same device to see how it behaves, but I won't be able to do that for about another month, since I won't have access to the device